# Как передать фокус на SVG иконку при клике на Input

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, css-animation

Появился вопрос о том, как передать фокус на иконку, но не могу найти эту иконку, ни по соседнему селектору, ни по рядом стоящему.

Я хочу, чтобы при `focus` сама иконка становилась красной, но сам фокус не передавался.

Решение хотелось бы увидеть без JavaScript или JQuery.

Попытка :

```css
.searchform input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

html,
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.searchform {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.searchform span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 0.23s linear;
}

input:focus~span {
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 12px;
}

input:focus {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.svgicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50px;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

input:focus+.svgicon>svg+g {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchform">
  <form action="">
    <label for="">
       <input type="search">
       <span>Найти</span>
        <div class="svgicon">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
            <g>
              <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="10"/>
              <line x1="15" y1="30" x2="10" y2="40" />
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.searchform input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

html,
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.searchform {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.searchform span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 0.23s linear;
}

input:focus~span {
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 12px;
}

input:focus {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.svgicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50px;
}

g {
  stroke: #000;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

line {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

input:focus ~ .svgicon > svg > g  {
   stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchform">
  <form action="">
    <label for="">
       <input type="search">
       <span>Найти</span>
        <div class="svgicon">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
            <g>
              <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="10" />
              <line x1="15" y1="30" x2="10" y2="40" />
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaximLensky Я там поменял чуть-чуть css, обрати внимание, что `stroke` для каждого элемента я убрал. Почему так работает, я не уверен, может кто-нибудь, кто лучше разбирается в svg, расскажет.

Comment: @MaximLensky и я разобрался. Получается, когда ты задавал `stroke` вложенным в `g` элементам, они переопределяли стили для `g`, что очевидно, хотя и не сразу понятно

Answer (score 4):

Как правильно догадались в комментариях, всё дело в стилях.
 У `SVG` с `CSS` довольно сложная система взаимодействия приоритетов стилей. Но это тема для отдельной статьи. В инете можно поискать, они есть и на хабре и в других местах.

Здесь, в частности, я удалил стили `stroke`, `fill`  для иконки (круг и линия) из правил CSS и перенес их в SVG.  Чтобы сработал клик, но окружность была прозрачная, - добавил `fill="transparent"`

**Вариант изменения цвета иконки после клика по ней самой**
Работает в `FireFox` и `Chrome`

```css
.searchform input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

html,
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.searchform {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.searchform span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 0.23s linear;
}

input:focus~span {
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 12px;
}

input:focus {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.svgicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50px;
}

circle {
   stroke-width: 2px;
}


line {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

input:focus+.svgicon>svg+g {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchform">
  <form action="">
    <label for="">
       <input id="input" type="search">
       <span>Найти</span>
        <div class="svgicon">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
            <g id="gr1" stroke="black" fill="transparent">
     
              <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="10"/>
              <line x1="15" y1="30" x2="10" y2="40" />
           </g>
   <animate xlink:href="#gr1" attributeName="stroke" begin="click" dur="0.5s" to="red" fill="freeze" />
          </svg>
        </div>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

:focus в CSS, это тоже самое, что событие `click` в SVG. Но событие click, срабатывает только на `id` по классу не работает. Поэтому я присвоил для Input `id="input"` в правилах CSS.

**Note**

Но изменение цвета иконки при клике на `Input`  работает только в Firefox, который более строго соблюдает стандарты `w3c` для SVG.
*В `Chrome` это не работает.*

```css
.searchform input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

html,
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.searchform {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.searchform span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 0.23s linear;
}

input:focus~span {
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 12px;
}

input:focus {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.svgicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50px;
}

circle {
   stroke-width: 2px;
}


line {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

input:focus+.svgicon>svg+g {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchform">
  <form action="">
    <label for="">
       <input id="input" type="search">
       <span>Найти</span>
        <div class="svgicon">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
            <g id="gr1" stroke="black" fill="transparent">
              <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="10"/>
              <line x1="15" y1="30" x2="10" y2="40" />
            
   </g>
   <animate
         xlink:href="#gr1"
         attributeName="stroke"
         begin="input.click"
         dur="0.5s"
         to="red"
         fill="freeze" />
          </svg>
        </div>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

*Возможно и есть костыльное решение, чтобы работало и в FF и Chrome, но мне кажется проще и надежней нарисовать иконку в CSS.*

Comment: @MaximLensky Я проверял, работает. У меня win10 и FF 71.0 (64-битный)

Comment: input:focus~.svgicon>svg>g

Comment: неправильно ведь комбинаторы расставлены

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex  это из оригинала в вопросе, я их не менял, так как понял, что всё равно не поможет :)))

Comment: Ну тогда какие-то странные примеры, потому что они не работают )

Comment: @MaximLensky я разве спорю, что `@hu-fo-of-ex` молодец, просто проверил, как сейчас SVG взаимодействует с CSS